# GTK+ How to ask for super user with prompt

Tags: c, linux, gtk, root

I am developing an application with GTK+-2.0. I need to access /dev/mmcblk0 device but it needs super user priviliges. It is not user friendly to login as su in terminal and run the program.

I want to create a prompt window and ask for super user password and run the program with super user priviliges. GParted is a program which runs in that way and I want a smilar opening procedure.

How can I achive that? How can I get super user privilidges in program?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the [gksu page](https://live.gnome.org/gksu) on live gnome, or if you want to use the [policy kit framework](https://live.gnome.org/PolicyKit) you can google for sample programs (e.g. [like this one](http://www.mail-archive.com/polkit-devel@lists.freedesktop.org/msg00142.html)).
Another way, more straightforward, would require the creation of a group (which would allow users to access /dev/mmcblk0) and ask root to add specific allowed users to this group.